# php script not running in fedora

Tags: php, linux, lamp

I was a windows user earlier and wants to shift to Linux. For that I have installed LAMP in my FC 15. But I am unable to run any php script there. I saved my files to `var/www/html` , but when I tried to run `http://localhost/test.php` it shows a blank page. 
NB:`rpm -q php` shows `php-5.4.9-1.fc15.remi.x86_64`.
Please help

Comment: Is your server status is in  start ? let us know what happens in http:localhost in your browser? do u have the open php in fedora ? check with php -v for version ? @Suraj Hazarika

Comment: When you go to test.php and right click page and view source do you see your PHP code?

Comment: `php -v` shows `PHP 5.4.9 (cli) (built: Nov 22 2012 10:37:24) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies`. `localhost/` shows a normal Fedora test page with powered by Apache

Comment: obviously the issue in php page...check with sample codes or update your code with posts.. will get you back with the issues..@Suraj Hazarika

Comment: you can use the binaries provided by your distribution - it is much simpler, dont wanna think about the external distributions

Comment: What does `test.php` contain?

Comment: Are there any meaningful contents in ``/var/log/httpd/error_log*``? On fedora, error output goes there by default.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the correct permissions set.

Comment: That would result in a 500 or 403 error, no? OP is getting a blank page so page is being served, but the PHP is not being processed by the looks of it.

Comment: `ls -l` shows `-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 23 Dec 14 18:19 test2.php
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  0 Dec 14 18:17 test.php
`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install php-common packages also

```
yum install php-common
```

will do.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following...

```
yum install php*
```

Install all the packages, then don't forget to restart apache/LAMP.

If still not coming, try `http://localhost/index.html` and tell the output if possible the  content of `httpd.conf` . The docroot may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and paste those two commands :

```
systemctl start httpd.service
```

and